# Python - How to split a list into two separate lists dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using Python-3 and I am reading a text file which can have multiple paragraphs separated by '\n'. I want to split all those paragraphs into a separate list. There can be n number of paragraphs in the input file.

So this split and output list creation should happen dynamically thereby allowing me to view a particular paragraph by just entering the paragraph number as list[2] or list[3], etc....

So far I have tried the below process :

```
input = open("input.txt", "r")  #Reading the input file
lines = input.readlines()       #Creating a List with separate sentences
str = ''                        #Declaring a empty string

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if len(lines[i]) > 2:       #If the length of a line is < 2, It means it can be a new paragraph
        str += lines[i]
```

This method will not store paragraphs into a new list (as I am not sure how to do it). It will just remove the line with '\n' and stores all the input lines into str variable. When I tried to display the contents of str, it is showing the output as words. But I need them as sentences.

**And my code should store all the sentences until first occurence of '\n' into a separate list and so on.**

Any ideas on this ?

**UPDATE** 
I found a way to print all the lines that are present until '\n'. But when I try to store them into the list, it is getting stored as letters, not as whole sentences. Below is the code snippet for reference

```
input = open("input.txt", "r")
lines = input.readlines()
input_ = []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    if len(lines[i]) <= 2:
        for j in range(i):
            input_.append(lines[j]) #This line is storing as letters.
```

even "input_ += lines" is storing as letters, Not as sentences.

Any idea how to modify this code to get the desired output ?

Comment: I don't believe you can create variables while the code is running.

Comment: @Krishi . why not. you can create or I believe atleast we can store all those paragraphs as elements in an array or list. But not sure how :(

Comment: Yes you can add each paragraph as a separate item in a list, but you can't put them all in different lists without knowing how many paragraphs there are while coding. If you wanna know how to add these paragraphs to a list, I'll post an answer.

Comment: To create a variable, it must be hard coded. You can't change or add variables while running the script, it must be done before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forgot to do `input.close()`, or the file won't save.

Alternatively you can use `with`.

```
#Using "with" closes the file automatically, so you don't need to write file.close()
with open("input.txt","r") as file:
    file_ = file.read().split("\n")
```

`file_` is now a list with each paragraph as a separate item.

It's as simple as 2 lines.

Comment: Hi . I am getting this error while executing your answer. AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Worked like a charm. Please provide it as an answer

Comment: Ok so you have edited this answer itself. That's better